# Calculate Statistics (Check if the answers are correct)

Tags: statistics, median

Calculate the statistics below using the following data on a sample of the variable $X$:

Data ($X$ sample) = $\{9, -1, 7, 0, -2, 5, 4, 9, 5 \}$

Using the sample data, calculate: Mean; Median; Mode; Range; Variance; Standard deviation; Coefficient of variation.

What I have (Please Check):

Mean: $4$

Median: $5$

Mode: $5,9$

Range: $11$

Variance: $17.25$

Standard deviation: $4.153311931$

Coefficient of variation: Standard Deviation/Mean $=1.038327983$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good to me!

Do your answers need to be rounded to a particular significant digit? (the last two computations, I'm referring to)...Seems you have a good grasp of this material.

Comment: No they don't. thanks again